# Wire *ALL* @Service level Spring beans in my XML config into a specific class

Tags: java, spring

I have a class - call it MsgRouting.java - in this class currently I access all Service level components. In my application I only use @Autowire, and I use Spring component scanning. Whilst, I realise, I can autowire all classes by base type- I do this elsewhere, but currently, not all my Service level beans inherit from the same base type; and I don't want to have to add a base type to all my Services.

Is there a way I can specify inside my XML Spring config that I want to have all Service level beans wired directly into the MsgRouting.java class? These are all @Service annotated.

I.e. I don't want to have to do this:

```
 @Autowire Service1 service1
 @Autowire Serviec2 service2 
 @Autowire Service3 ... ad infinitum

 service1.doStuff();
 service2.doOtherStuff();
 service3.calculateSomething();
```

rather something like this:

```
 <bean id="RouteIncomingNetMSG" class="uk.co.foo.MsgRouting">
        <gimme>
</bean>
```

then inside MsgRouting, just

```
 service1.doStuff();
```

Thanks!

Comment: this should work with <context:component-scan base-package="your.service.package"/> + <context:annotation-config> in your config.xml. Or am i missunderstanding your question?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I want all classes inside my services package, XML wired into my routeMsg class. I'm already using base-package scan. However, i'm talking about a lot of Autowiring annotations, which I want to avoid in my code.

Comment: Ok, you could try to use reflections in InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet() method, to find all the private service-fields, determine if there is a bean in the context with the same interface and set it there. I've never tried this, but popped up into my mind as a possible solution. Do you need an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to have a common base class but at least a common interface.
As otherwise you would not be able to call you "doStuff" anyway.
In this case you can just auto wire a list of that interface

```
@Autowired
List<ServiceInterface> services;
```

While your service classes look like:

```
@Service
public class Service1 implements ServiceInterface {...}
```

**Edit:**
You could of course also just inject

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("MyServices")
List<Object> services;
```

and then would just get everything that has a corresponding qualifier attached. But in my oppinion that would be bad design.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the original question, I don't want to have to use a common interface for all my services. I was hoping there might be another way to do this.

Comment: See my edit. You can also just get "everything" by injecting a list of objects. But still you need then a common qualifier. Anyhow an interface is not a common base class.

Comment: I said 'base type' I think! But thank you for your answer. I was hoping to specify a constructor-arg using some kind of wild card in my XML config.

Comment: If you want to do it via XML configuration and do a configured list of services there than you can also create configurations like described in http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-collections.html Example 3.19